# vlookup function for e-mail addresses (text); if value is TRUE then "statement" [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I want to compare two sheets. I need a function that is comparing the e-mail addresses given in Sheet1!C:C with the e-mail addresses given in Sheet2!C:C. If there should be a match, I want the status in Sheet1!D:D to be set on "consent received", ELSE "pending".

Here's an [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mIygh4ldkBv2Kwo0BORdVM5iR1Y7djzCkOBZy8veBeM/edit#gid=1301723600).

I tried it with this function:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$100,1,FALSE)),"consent received","pending")
```

But this doesn't do the trick.

Comment: What error did  your code get?

Comment: No error, the results just have been incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

D2:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C7,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$100,1,FALSE)),"pending", "consent received"))
```